# Make images in Gmail non-clickable

Tags: html, image, email, gmail, salesforce-marketing-cloud

Is it possible, using HTML, to make the image of an email non-clickable when it is opened from Gmail (to avoid that pop-up from where you can download the image)? I read something about using href='#' but it not always work.

I am building the emails in Salesforce Marketing Cloud, in case it helps.

Comment: I didn't test it, but try to set background image of a simple empty div

Comment: Not tested : Set inline CSS pointer-events:none on image